# animate({top}) snaps horizontally at completion

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need some help, I'll appreciate any advise.  Consider a `position:relative` `div`, inside of it three `position:absolute` divs with class `page`.  The point is to open the pages with a transition similar to an inverted slideUp- slideDown in jQ.

The problem is: The transition snaps horizontally, which is not good. Also how can `#mainContainer` be vertically centered?

You can see a demo of the problem in http://jsfiddle.net/4zaWz/

Here is the code:

```
function setMenu(menuItem) {
    var $activePage = $('.active-page');

    if ($activePage.length > 0) {
        $activePage.animate({ top: 584 }, 500, function () {
            $activePage.removeClass('active-page');
        });
    }

    var $menuCur = $("#" + menuItem);
    $menuCur.animate({ top: 0 }, 500, function () {
        $menuCur.addClass('active-page');
    });
}
```

```
#mainContainer
{
    position: relative;
    height: 565px;
    width: 990px;
    margin: auto;
    background: url(../img/logo.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.page
{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 4px;
    height: 584px;
    width: 864px;
    top:584px;
    background: url(../img/pageBg.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

.active-page

{
    top:0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 30;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When items in jQuery animate they set to a position:absolute. So, in this case, it breaks your animation because it breaks your CSS where you are changing page FROM absolute TO relative. If you just remove relative on .active-page you'll be fine. You'll need to figure out a way to keep "active" and just the normal page the same "position". I'll keep playing with it tho.

Now, to center something with absolute positions it's simply:

http://jsbin.com/emaku6/5/

(take the width of the window and the element, divide them by 2 [half] then subtract them)

Comment: Also, remove "z-index" in active page OR set it in your normal page CSS

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/GDFBt/

As Oscar mentioned, the problem were 2 conflicting `position`'s--I made the .active-page absolute, and changed the `left` property to center the page.